# Elastic Cloud | How and why to handle Kibana resources when creating deploy

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-cloud

I am wondering which would be the reasons/use-cases that would require to assign Kibana high RAM, CPU and zone resources.

I mean, it's clear what does this means for Elasticsearch component (I/O efficiency). But how these variables affect Kibana performance? What different use cases there are where these resources might/must be handled differently?
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the some of the you can consider while creating Kibana instance:

- Number of simultaneous connetions to Kibana
- simultaneous editing request the dashboards
- the number of accesses to the shared dashboard
- high Reporting functionality (which requires CPU)
- large reporting jobs / alert jobs
- number of space you are creating

Basically, you need to consider what all functionality you are going to use from Kibana. If you have limited usage of kibana then you can go with either first or second option from list.